# My Dell Latitude screen just went black

Tags: display

My Dell just went completely black! When I look closer I can barely see the desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: For future reference, you probably want to include the fact that you're talking about the builtin laptop screen.  Assuming you are.

Comment: Wave your mouse around and take it out of screen saver. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backlight is off.  Others are probably right that it died, but try fiddling with your brightness controls first.  I've had laptops where something happened and the brightness controls would actually allow you to turn the backlight off while not disabling the display.

Answer (score 1):

The monitor is probably dead.

If it's under guarantee, make a claim from Dell.
If it's not under guarantee, find a repairman or pay Dell.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the very same thing happen.

My local shop replaced the inverter ($20) and all is well.

It may be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What model also?

I have seen plenty of 6420s and 5430s (So the more current models) where the ribbon works itself loose. Removing the screen from the chassis and reconnecting the ribbon fixes it.